# How to get the datetime from database in neo4j

Tags: datetime, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using `2.2.5 neo4j version`, I have millions of real flights. I have arrival time and departure time in `datetime` format.

For example:  I have departure time format 2011-03-23 02:40:00 arrival time format 2011-03-23 06:20:00.

My question is I stored them in string format when I tired to convert in `toint` I got null. I can't find the duration of the flights. How can I calculate the duration of flights.

Thanks in Advance, your cooperation is truly appreciated!

Comment: Why not store your date as a timestamp ? toInt function convert string to int, but not date.

Comment: [tag:logisima]So Is it possible to calculate duration with timestamp.

Comment: Neo4j knows how to make a subtraction between to int. You should make the convertion from datetime to timestamp into your app, not in cypher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortuantely Neo4j doesn't support dates / times natively yet.  This includes both property types and date / time support functions.  I believe that this is planned.

What you should probably do is to store an integer in the database.  You can do this either as an addition to your datetime string (which is nice because you, as a programmer, can read it easily), or you could just store the integer.

I'd advise doing this is your programming language of choice.  I started to do it in Cypher by parsing the string but then I remembered that [that way leads to madness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).  If you'd like to try you can use the `substring` and `toInt` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.4, there are native date/time types: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.4-changelog .

For now, many use APOC https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_and_time_conversions

or just time since epoch and convert/format within their language of choice.

Source: https://twitter.com/ryguyrg/status/987780879291375616